# react-toastify showing twice with SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get react-toastify working with Next.js but get the following error:

`Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching text node for "nz6teoigav" in <div>.`

This causes the toast component to render twice.

Inside `_app.tsx` I added `<ToastContainer position='top-center' newestOnTop={true} limit={1} />`

Then in different components I can call `toast.error('error')`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing an example of the problem, it's a guessing game. That said here's a working codesandbox with react-toastify and NextJS that you can use/reference in your project:

[Codesandbox Source](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-react-toastify-ujr4m)

[Working Codesandbox Demo](https://ujr4m.sse.codesandbox.io/)

The above example utilizes a custom `toast` function that alters the message appearance, however it's **completely optional** and only there for demonstrations purposes.